# CLion finds a wrong function signature

Tags: c++, c++11, clion

I constantly have CLion editor showing me parameter type mismatch errors while during build everything is fine. For example, consider the following MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>

using namespace std;

namespace bc = boost::container;

int main() {
    bc::flat_set<bc::flat_set<int>> manySets;
    bc::flat_set<int> oneSet({1, 2, 3});
    manySets.insert(oneSet);
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here `flat_set` is a template from `boost` library (description could be seen [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_set.html)). Editor shows me an error:
[image: CLion editor displays an error in tooltip]

But when I build it (even from CLion), everything is compiled fine.

My system is:

- Ubuntu 15.10 64bit
- CLion 1.2.4

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a known problem - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6027. We hope to fix it soon.